# Zend Framework Config file JSON

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

Currently I'm learning ZF2. While going through "Getting start", I see that each config file for module is quite filled with PHP arrays. An example from documentation:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Array with array in it with array. Actually I know, that array is just name of function and it's more like map with key/value pair.

One of the Zend MODS pointed that we can use JSON for config files:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html#comment-696979913

Does anyone can provide example for beginner? I'd really prefer to use JSON format for those file configs instead of arrays/map, but I couldn't find it on ZF homepage. Or maybe I shouldn't do it?

Comment: I'd advise against using JSON. Some time down the track you'll want to create a one line factory for the ServiceManager in your config file, and then you'll need it in php.

Comment: If all the `array(`'s annoy you and make it look ugly, then use php 5.4's `[]` array syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try modifying the `getConfig()` function inside your `Module.php` file:

```
return \Zend\Config\Factory::fromFile(__DIR__ . '/config/module.config.json', false);
```